# How to "publish" without dreamweaver

Tags: html, web, server, dreamweaver

Context:

I was recently put in charge of the website for my organization. The current site is only static HTML and we need some database backed stuff. I can handcode HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I understand how to make a server and all of that but the current website was managed via dreamweaver, which I have never used. The site is hosted on a server I don't control (belongs to our parent organization who are not set up to handle this kind of thing on their server). I want to just throw a redirect on the old site and manage my own server or get hosting that allows me to control the back end. My predecessor told me to hit publish on dreamweaver and fill in the SFTP Address, Username, Password, Root Directory, and Web URL. I get what is going on here but I have no clue how to do this without dreamweaver. Their must be a way. I could get the trial of dreamweaver and use it to make this one change but it makes me uncomfortable that after the month I will be unable to access a page I am responsible for. This feels like something very basic I should know so I am sorry if this is a ridiculous question. Thanks in advance.

Cut to the question:

How do I replicate the "publish" action of dreamweaver if I have the SFTP Address, Username, Password, Root Directory, and Web URL of the target server?

Comment: I don't know what Dreamweaver's "Publish" does exactly - does it check which parts of the site need to be updated? What does it do in case of conflicts? etc. - but to upload stuff onto a web site, you would typically use a FTP client like Filezilla

Comment: Thanks this looks like it would work. Thanks so much for the help. Sorry my question was so basic.

Comment: Errr, copy the directory to the server using an FTP client?

Answer (score 0):

publisb just connects to server and upload all th files. Whih you could just do manually if you know how. I typically gzip all my files an uploa that an then ungzip it frm server-side if you have access to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data to log in, you can use the normal ftp connection to upload and download your files. Myself I run filezilla next to my notepad++ and cross check what I update. But my choice is just one in a million. If you have a cpanel, there is a file manager and a backup tool. You can  use those to download your backup and put it back when its not working probably. The file manager lets you upload and download specific files. This is, if you have cpanel installed as your control panel of your server.